# MahApps NumericUpDown make up down buttons bigger

Tags: wpf, numericupdown, mahapps.metro

I'm working on a wpf project that uses the Mahapps NumericUpDown.
In order to make it more touch friendly, I'ld like to make the up and downbuttons a bit bigger.

I've tried setting the height and width bigger of the whole numericUpDown control, but this only makes the buttons height bigger (the width seems to be fixed)

I also tried wrapping the NumericUpDown in a viewbox. This makes everything bigger. The problem is that the numbers in the textbox are also bigger, making it look very alien to the rest of the controls on the screen.

Any ideas on any better solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know when it was added, but the `NumericUpDown` Control has a `UpDownButtonsWidth` Property:

```
<mah:NumericUpDown
    UpDownButtonsWidth="60"/>
```

The `+` and `-` buttons get wider accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I am the developer of `NumericUpDown` in `MahApps`.

A solution is to change in `NumericUpDown.xaml` the `Path.Data` in `PolygonUp` and `PolygonDown` or to change the Contentent of `PART_NumericUp` and `PART_NumericDown`.

Comment: Thanx for the quick reply. Actually we use the normal size, only in touch mode the buttons should be bigger. I was wondering if a style could be made based on the default style that could make those buttons bigger, so we could assign that style to the NumericUpDown when in touch mode. Not sure if that is possible.